# Write a simple Interface (with nothing in it) called Child and use it to create an ArrayList that can store instances of Boy and Girl only

Tags: java, list, generics, arraylist, interface

I am answering a revision question and I'm kinda stuck on how to answer it.

The Question goes like this:

Suppose we have the following class definition outlines:

```
public abstract class Person { ... }

public class Man extends Person { ... }

public class Woman extends Person { ... } 

public class Boy extends Person { ... } 

public class Girl extends Peron { ... }
```

i. Create an `ArrayList` that can store any instance of the classes `Man`/`Woman`/`Boy`/`Girl` using the above class definitions, but will not allow instances of `Animal` or any other classes.

ii. Write a simple Interface (with nothing in it) called `Child` and use it to create an `ArrayList` that can store instances of `Boy` and `Girl` only (i.e. and not `Man` or `Woman`).

The 1st I assume the answer is the one below.

```
ArrayList <Person> list = new ArrayList<Person>();
```

But for the 2nd part of the question I'm not sure how to answer it. I assume it has something to do with Java generics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would create the `Child` interface.

```
interface Child {}
```

Make `Boy` and `Girl` implement it.

```
public class Boy extends Person implements Child { ... }

public class Girl extends Person implements Child { ... }
```

And then use the interface as generic type for the list.

```
ArrayList<Child> list = new ArrayList<>();
```

*Side note*

Always try to [program to interfaces](https://stackoverflow.com/q/383947/5640649). Instead of `ArrayList` as reference use `List`.

```
List<Child> list = new ArrayList<>();
```

Answer (score 3):

Create the interface, make only Boy and Girl implement it, and make it a list of Child instead. You need to update just 3 lines.